# Clone project with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning JAVA with Eclipse (ADT , Latest version - For Android development).
Each lesson we enhance the *same* project.   *(I don't like this approach)*
So - I want to create different project for *each* lesson so :
Each lesson I'm cloning the main folder - and then I import it as an existing project.
( I thought that cloning + renaming the folder - would be fine)

But :

Eclipse says that the project already exists. (make sense)

**Question**

If I have a folder that contains a project ( `LeadoMat`) :

[image]

, And I'm creating folder `LeadoMat_Ver2` ( cloned files)

— How/What should I do in order for eclipse to accept it as a new project named : `LeadoMat_Ver2` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The project folder contains a file called `.project`. In your cloned project, open that file with any text editor and look for the project name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>LeadoMat</name>
    <!-- more stuff here -->
</projectDescription>
```

Change the content of the `name` element to `LeadoMat_Ver2`. You should now be able to import the project into Eclipse.

Answer (score 66):

The simplest approach would probably be to do the copying right in `eclipse`:

```
Right Click your Project -> Copy
Right Click in the Project Explorer -> Paste

or

CTRL + C & CTRL + V
```

Eclipse will then automatically prompt you to enter a new name for the clone. Then you'll have a full copy of your project with the new name.

---

The reason why `eclipse` thinks that it is the same project, is because you also clone the `.project`-files which contain the name of the project used in `eclipse`.

Comment: First time Java-World made something simpler, wasn't expecting such an easy process.

Comment: @EralpB They had to do something to keep the kittens from getting set on fire.

Comment: If you have an Ant task, you need to make sure its xml configuration and the makejar.launch do not contain references to the original name of the project

Answer (score 0):

Right Click and **choose** Copy (to copy project that you want to clone)
Right Click on blank area on Package Explorer tab choose **Paste**
Input project name
wait and you have a new one